# BreakPoint не работает: Нет загруженных символов для файла Guard.cs

Tags: c#, winforms

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В настоящий момент попадание в точку останова не произойдёт. Нет загруженных символов для этого документа.
Расположение Guard.cs, строка 38 знак 9(DooDHack_v2.Main_Window.Guard.Render())

Использую WinForms 4.8. Ошибка появилась неожиданно.
Пробовал то, что пишут в дубликатах(В основном С++),
Пробовал подключить сайт с символами через `Средства > Параметры > Отладка > Символы`,
Пробовал загрузить все символы в хэш,
Пробовал включать отладку машинного кода, итог - не работает

Comment: Пересоберите полностью решение, символы в pdb файле. Ничего ниоткуда подключать не нужно.

Comment: @aepot, Как именно? Удалить репу с пк и скачать её с гита?

Comment: Удалить папки bin и obj

Comment: @aepot, не помогло

Comment: после сборки смотреть, есть ли в выходной папке pdb файл

Comment: Есть, название моего решения.pdb 300кб весит

Comment: В нем и лежат символы, студия при отладке должна автоматом их хватать. Если это не происходит, то надо искать причину. Я к тому что цеплять дополнительно ничего не нужно, все у вас есть.

Comment: @aepot, 
1. Используйте конфигурацию отладочной сборки или отключите параметр отладки "Включить только мой код". 
2. Проверьте параметры раздела "Символы" в настройках отладки."DooDHack v2.exe" (Win32). Загружено "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clrjit.dll".

Answer (score 1):

Я много что пробовал, но случился похоже новый случай ошибки, Нужно было выключить "Оптимизация кода"

Comment: Кто ж с оптимизацией отлаживает то. Мне даже в голову не пришло, но тема известная.

Comment: Странно что она в дебаге, а не только в релизе работает

Comment: Оно отдельно для дебага и релиза настраивается.